# Reuniting two dictionaries with key-value in common

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have two dictionaries and i want to compare them based on the supporterId key like so:

```
dict1 = [{'name': 'John', 'supporterId': 1}, {'name': 'Paul', 'supporterId': 2}]
dict2 = [{'dependent': 'Erick','supporterId': 2}, {'dependent': 'Anna', 'email': 'anna@gmail.com', 'supporterId': 2}, {'dependent': 'George','email': 'george@gmail.com',supporterId': 13}]
```

and I need to check if the supporterId between dict1 and dict2 are equal and if so put the name_dependent inside the corresponding supporterId in a so for example the output to this should be:

```
dict3 = {'name': 'Paul', 'supporterId': 2, 'dependent_name': ['George', 'Anna'], dependent_email: ['anna@gmail.com', 'george@gmail.com']}]
```

Comment: You could do this a couple ways in pure python, what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried using for loops and comparisons but it didnt work

Comment: As you're learning, I strongly recommend you post what you did so we can see where you went wrong and explain it. Just getting an answer isn't likely to help much, but if that's what you want someone will answer soon.

Comment: Seconding @ᴓᴓᴓ that you should post what you already have. This seems like a homework assignment tbh and users here don't like just straight up doing someones homework for them, rather we'd prefer to help you see what your mistake was